# Is it possible to force sidecar over bluetooth instead of Wi-FI?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, wifi, bluetooth, sidecar

There's been a lot of questions and discussions regarding SideCar connectivity.

I cannot use USB as it drains my MacBook to charge the iPad (and there's no AlDente for iPad :(). Is it possible to force Bluetooth over Wi-Fi in hopes of getting a better connection?

All help and suggestions are appreciated!

MacBook Air M2 - 15" (Sonoma 14.1.2 (23B92))

iPad Air (5th gen)(iPadOS 16.6)

Comment: I do not believe the BT and WiFi have compatible protocols and operating frequencies

Comment: BT and WiFi both operate in the 2.4GHz range of frequencies and a protocol is the methodology used by devices to transact data; its device agnostic.  So, it’s unclear what you were saying with you comment.

Comment: It's not clear why using Wifi is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not supported; you'll need Wi-Fi to use Sidecar wirelessly. Bluetooth also generally lacks the required bandwidth for monitor-quality video streaming, as it maxes out at 50 Mbps (even for the latest revision.) In any case, Bluetooth uses the same 2.4 GHz band as low-bandwidth Wi-Fi; there's no reason that Bluetooth should provide an inherent benefit.

[image]